# mysqldump cannot connect using socket

Tags: bash, ubuntu, mysql

This issue has been racking my brain for a few hours. I have been trying to use mysqldump to dump a database, using:

```
mysqldump --protocol=socket -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock database`
```

However, I keep getting:

`1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect`

I am on localhost and running under root (*sudo su*).
*Root@localhost* is allowed in the mysql user table.
I can use `> mysql` to view all of the databases, but mysqldump will not work.
I do not know the root password (system generated).
I have tried adding the socket to the *my.conf* like so and restarting the mysql server:

> `[mysqldump]`
>   `socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution! The socket does not hold the credentials itself. They are stored in the `/root/.my.cnf` configuration file instead. Mine only had the username and password for the `mysql` command. I needed to add `[mysqldump]` to it as well. Here is what my `/root/.my.cnf` file looks like now:

> `[mysql]`
>   `user=root`
>   `pass=myawesomepass`
>
> `[mysqldump]`
>   `user=root`
>   `pass=myawesomepass`

Answer (score 15):

Even though you are connecting via the socket, you must still give the user `root`

If `root@localhost` has no password then do this:

```
mysqldump -uroot --protocol=socket -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock database
```

If `root@localhost` has a password then do this:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --protocol=socket -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock database
```

If running

```
mysql
```

lets you login with specifying `-uroot`, try not specifying the socket either

```
mysqldump database
```

I just noticed that the socket you specified for mysqldump is

```
[mysqldump]
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

You need to make sure the socket is defined under the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf` as well

If this does not exist

```
[mysqld]
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

then run this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'socket';
```

and make sure of the socket file's name and path.

You could have you System DBA add a custom user for you

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO tyler@localhost;
```

Then, you can run

```
mysqldump -utyler --protocol=socket -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock database
```

This is not secure. tyler should have a password. So, run this:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO tyler@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'tylerspasssword';
```

then you can do

```
mysqldump -utyler -p --protocol=socket -S /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock database
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no go. `Root@localhost` does have a password, but it was generated by the server. I was originally running `mysqldump database` but it was giving the same error and thought the socket needed to be specified. `mysql` runs without `-uroot`, but `mysqldump` still gives the error. Ideas?

Comment: The socket has been defined under `[mysqld]`. I copied that line to the `[mysqldump]` part for good measure.

Comment: The same path: `| socket        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |`

Comment: When you login to mysql, please run this query `SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();` and tell me the output.

Comment: `| root@localhost | root@localhost |` :/ Is the password required. All of my searches had the password part. I just figured one would be able to use the socket without the password instead.

Comment: Found a solution. See my answer. Thanks for the help!